# How to ignore namespaces when selecting XML nodes with XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I saw that there is an option to ignore namespace

```
 xpathUtil.getObjectValue("//*[local-name() = 'object name']")
```

is it possible to add more objetcs names

for example

```
  <Schema xmlns:m...... Namespace="app"
   xmlns:d = ....
  <complexType Name = "Comp>
  <EntityType Name = "a">
  <EntityType Name = "b">
  </Schema>

 <Schema xmlns:m...... Namespace="app2"
   xmlns:d = ....
  <complexType Name = "Comp2>
  <EntityType Name = "a2">
  <EntityType Name = "b2">
  </Schema>
```

is it possible to get the data of the attribute EntityType only for Schema= app ? ( meaning to get the result of a and b and not a2 and b2 )

Comment: Looking at your example I'm not quite sure which exact context you would like to use the namespace in: is at a) just a attribute to the `<Schema>` tag? In this case you can you can simply filtering by this attribute, e.g. `"//Schema[@Namespace="XXX"]/..."`. Or is it b) a true namespace declaration to your `<Schema>` tag, in which case the example would be missing the namespace prefixes.

Comment: I meant it is possible don't use the namespace prefixes and to use the local-name() but to get more attribute like xpathUtil.getObjectValue("//*[local-name() = 'Schema']/EntityType") and also I want to get value of EntityType only for Schema that the Namespace is app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a complete version of your input file might look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Schemas>
  <ns1:Schema xmlns:ns1="app1" >
    <ns1:complexType Name = "Comp1">
      <ns1:EntityType Name = "a1"/>
      <ns1:EntityType Name = "b1"/>
    </ns1:complexType>
  </ns1:Schema>

  <ns2:Schema xmlns:ns2="app2">
    <ns2:complexType Name = "Comp2">
      <ns2:EntityType Name = "a2"/>
      <ns2:EntityType Name = "b2"/>
    </ns2:complexType>
  </ns2:Schema>
</Schemas>
```

the following XSLT shows how to filter the tags by the URI of the namespaceand the name of the namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="ns_uri1" select="'app1'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ns_uri2" select="'app2'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ns_name1" select="'ns1'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ns_name2" select="'ns2'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Schemas">

    <apps>
      <app1_selected_by_namespace_uri>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name(.) = 'Schema' and namespace-uri(.)=$ns_uri1]"/>
      </app1_selected_by_namespace_uri>

      <app2_selected_by_namespace_uri>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name(.) = 'Schema' and namespace-uri(.)=$ns_uri2]"/>
      </app2_selected_by_namespace_uri>

      <app1_selected_by_namespace_name>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[name(.) = concat($ns_name1, ':Schema')]"/>
      </app1_selected_by_namespace_name>

      <app2_selected_by_namespace_name>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[name(.) = concat($ns_name2, ':Schema')]"/>
      </app2_selected_by_namespace_name>
    </apps>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

yielding the following output document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apps>
  <app1_selected_by_namespace_uri>
    <ns1:Schema xmlns:ns1="app1">
    <ns1:complexType Name="Comp1">
      <ns1:EntityType Name="a1"/>
      <ns1:EntityType Name="b1"/>
    </ns1:complexType>
  </ns1:Schema>
  </app1_selected_by_namespace_uri>
  <app2_selected_by_namespace_uri>
    <ns2:Schema xmlns:ns2="app2">
    <ns2:complexType Name="Comp2">
      <ns2:EntityType Name="a2"/>
      <ns2:EntityType Name="b2"/>
    </ns2:complexType>
  </ns2:Schema>
  </app2_selected_by_namespace_uri>
  <app1_selected_by_namespace_name>
    <ns1:Schema xmlns:ns1="app1">
    <ns1:complexType Name="Comp1">
      <ns1:EntityType Name="a1"/>
      <ns1:EntityType Name="b1"/>
    </ns1:complexType>
  </ns1:Schema>
  </app1_selected_by_namespace_name>
  <app2_selected_by_namespace_name>
    <ns2:Schema xmlns:ns2="app2">
    <ns2:complexType Name="Comp2">
      <ns2:EntityType Name="a2"/>
      <ns2:EntityType Name="b2"/>
    </ns2:complexType>
  </ns2:Schema>
  </app2_selected_by_namespace_name>
</apps>
```

In both cases the names are not hardcoded but given by parameters. I guess that one of the versions will suit your needs. You will find the XPath expression in the `select` attributes of the `copy-of` tags.